# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::results()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am very new to CodeIgniter. I am getting below error. Can someone please help me out. I checked various answers on StackOverflow but none helped me.

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::results()

Filename: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/CodeIgniter/application/controllers/Stud_controller.php

Line Number: 10

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/codeigniter/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Below is the controller code

```
<?php
Class Stud_controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function index(){
        $query = $this->db->get("stud");
        $data['records'] = $query -> results();
        $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

And this is the view code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang = "en">

   <head> 
      <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
      <title>Students Example</title> 
   </head>
   <body>
        <a href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>
         index.php/stud/add_view">Add</a>
   </body>

</html>
```

Currently not using the data coming from controller.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: also u can use $query -> result()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use something like this

```
$data['records'] = $query -> result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use:

```
$query = $this->db->get("stud")->result();
```

or

```
$query = $this->db->get("stud")->result_array();
```

To access the data you can put the **$query** in a foreach like the examples below and access it as an object or as an array.

You have two kind of approaches:

**result()**

> This method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an
>   empty array on failure.

Example:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

or **result_array()**

> This method returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty
>   array when no result is produced.

Example:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['body'];
}
```

[Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)